# Fonts of some applications get confused

Tags: debian, fonts, evince

I am running Debian Testing with LXDE.

After some time of work, some applications begin to show confused fonts, as shown in the following screenshot (the pdf specific area is good):

[image]

This happens with `evince` and with notification (sent from `wicd`, `clementine`, etc., I suppose through `notify-send`).

Cannot say what other applications show the problem, but almost all other applications work good, for example `iceweasel` (firefox), `icedove` (thunderbird), `xchat`, `lxterminal`, etc.

How to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Probably related: [Degraded areas of some user interfaces, including pixellated or jagged fonts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/263252/13260); "… it seems that the problem may affect multiple desktop environments in both Linux and FreeBSD …". enzotib, did you find a solution or explanation to the problem(s) in your case?

Comment: @GrahamPerrin: no, simply moved to other distro / desktop env.