# Degraded areas of some user interfaces, including pixellated or jagged fonts

Tags: linux, freebsd, configuration, fonts, gui

For me the symptoms were [first observed with PC-BSD 11.0-CURRENT](https://forums.pcbsd.org/thread-20535.html). The first of my 2016 screenshots (below) is similar to the 2012 shot in Debian-related [Fonts of some applications get confused](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31279/13260) so, reading the two questions alongside each other:

- it *seems* that the problem/symptoms may affect **multiple desktop environments** in **both Linux and FreeBSD**.

From my screenshots:

- please, can anyone guess what's wrong?

Hint: to clearly view the symptoms, you may find it necessary to view each shot full-size.

In my case it's *certain* that symptoms are present for multiple users and multiple desktop environments – and most (maybe all) packages have been reinstalled. So:

- **I guess that the problem is with a configuration file that is shared** (not in any home directory).

I tested a new user account, the problem persisted.

### Screenshots

#### Document Viewer (Evince)

Poorly rendered fonts in the toolbar and sidebar of the application:

[image: pixellated fonts in the GUI of Document Viewer]

#### Xterm

Poorly rendered font within the terminal window:

[image: A screenshot of Konsole and Xterm]

#### Luxi Sans medium and Terminal in xfontsel

The poorly rendered font sample in the lowest part of the application window (although from commentary below, and from glancing at xfontsel on a different computer, it may be that the pixellation is to be expected in this application):

[image: pixellated font sample of Luxi Sans medium in xfontsel]

[image: pixellated font sample of Terminal in xfontsel]

#### Xfburn

[image]

### Comparisons

The shot of Xfburn may be most telling; the degraded appearance is not limited to fonts. Compare what's above with a 2010 shot (from [Xfburn – A tool the size of the task | Written and Read](http://writtenandread.net/xfburn/comment-page-1/index.html)):

[image: 2010 screenshot of Xfburn, by Morten Juhl-Johansen Zölde-Fejér]

When I choose a PC-BSD 10.2-RELEASE boot environment on the affected machine, there's no problem. In this shot from 10.2, (GNOME) System Monitor appears fine:

[image: GNOME System Monitor on PC-BSD 10.2-RELEASE]

### Additional notes

When I logged in to MATE, the fonts in its menu bar were pixellated.

Without running X, I ran the following command to force reinstallation (or upgrade) of all packages –

```
pkg upgrade -f
```

– then restarted the operating system. That pkg routine did not work around the problem.

As far as I can tell, the poor font rendering is no better when VESA mode applies.

#### Shortlist of some affected applications

- Files (nautilus) 3.18.5
- Gnote 3.18.1
- HexChat 2.10.2
- Pidgin 2.10.12 (libpurple 2.10.12)
- System Monitor (gnome-system-monitor) 3.16.0
- Web (epiphany) 3.16.3
- Xfburn 0.5.4
- XTerm 322

#### Shortlist of some non-affected applications

At a glance:

- Firefox 44.0.2
- Konsole 2.14.2
- Konversation 1.5.1
- KSnapshot 0.8.2
- System Log (KSystemLog) 0.4
- Thunderbird 38.6.0

### GTK

Neither `/usr/local/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` nor `/usr/local/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` exists –

```
$ cat /usr/local/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
cat: /usr/local/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc: No such file or directory
$ ls -al /usr/local/etc/gtk-2.0/
total 9
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    3  8 Feb 20:26 .
drwxr-xr-x  67 root  wheel  154 21 Feb 22:25 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  890  5 Feb 13:52 im-multipress.conf
$ cat /usr/local/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
cat: /usr/local/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini: No such file or directory
$ ls -al /usr/local/etc/gtk-3.0/
total 9
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    3 21 Feb 22:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  67 root  wheel  154 21 Feb 22:25 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  890 16 Feb 22:08 im-multipress.conf
$
```

– from a separate installation of PC-BSD 11.0-CURRENTJAN2016 it seems, that's the norm. From discussion in irc://chat.freenode.net/#pcbsd it's assumed that their nonexistence implies default values.

### Selected comments from beyond Stack Exchange

From a developer:

> Sorry Graham, I don't really have an idea of what could be causing this. Looks like gtk is going nuts on your system, or some lower-level X issues.
>
> Good luck …

---

### Background

As far as I recall, the problem in my case arose from intentionally aggressive testing of PC-BSD 11.0-CURRENTFEB2016 with [portmaster(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=portmaster&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports). During a run of portmaster, probably –

```
sudo portmaster -GaD
```

– I launched a type of application that might cause the hardware ([Ergo Vista 621](https://forums.pcbsd.org/thread-20235.html) notebook with Intel GM45 graphics) to blackout with anything more recent than 11.0-CURRENTNOV2015. Sure enough, a blackout occurred with no response to Control-Alt-F2 and so I pressed the power button to shut down the system as gracefully as possible in the midst of works by portmaster.

I have ZFS boot environments for both 11.0-CURRENTNOV2015 and 11.0-CURRENTFEB2016. Since the problem occurred whilst testing the latter, the symptom is present in both environments.

Comment: A problem in some antialiasing tool, like infinality? Also you "guess" the problem is not in users' config files: did you try with a fresh user account? The rendering I get in xfontsel is not better than yours: probably not abnormal. So, can you confirm this is a GTK-only issue, by running many Qt apps and many GTK apps?

Comment: infinality is not in FreshPorts, I guess that's for Linux only. I don't know how to tell the difference between GTK and Qt applications, but I edited the question to include shortlists of affected and non-affected applications. Edited also to show that the problem _does_ affect a fresh user account.

Comment: Mostly, KDE stuff is Qt-based and Gnome&Xfce stuff is GTK-based. So it looks like a GTK problem, *except* that XTerm is affected. Are you sure it is as badly affected as the other (GTK) apps? Or just like xfontsel? You could make xfontsel display your XTerm font and compare.

Answer (score 5):

### Without identifying the troublesome package

Laziness – without the desired learning.

Instead of performing a change of branch from 10.2-RELEASE to 11.0-CURRENT, I **removed from 11.0-CURRENTNOV2015** most of the **packages that were not of immediate interest** to me.

Now XTerm and various other applications appear good. An example:

[image: screen shot of XTerm looking good]

#### xfontsel

> … [probably not abnormal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263252/degraded-areas-of-some-user-interfaces-including-pixellated-or-jagged-fonts#comment458812_263252) …

Yes. Now I see that rendering in xfontsel is relatively poor.

### Identification of the package that most likely caused the problem

From the details below, someone might recognise a likely culprit.

If an additional answer helps me to identify the offending package, I'll happily:

- accept; and then (after I regain sufficient reputation)
- award a bounty.

---

### Details of removals

Using [pkg(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&sektion=7)

#### Round one

Focused on removal of some desktop environments.

`icewm` was remarkable:

- preparation for removal suggested that two packages were to be removed
- deinstallation counted nothing.

So I used `pkg` to (re)install icewm –

- installation counted nothing

– then remove it:

- deinstallation counted one package.

#### Round two (outline)

I used `pkg` to set to non-automatic the packages that I wished to keep.

Then the `autoremove` command of `pkg` to –

> Delete packages which were automatically installed as dependencies and are not required any more.

– then removal of some other stuff (probably relating to MATE), then another `autoremove` routine.

Finally I attended to a handful of packages that I wanted to reinstall (evince, gnome-characters, gnome-screenshot, gnome-system-monitor, nautilus, xfontsel).

#### Selected outputs from terminal windows

```
[root@cces3-gjp4-pc-bsd-ergovista621] /usr/home/gjp4# pkg set -A 0 DTraceToolkit ; pkg set -A 0 ImageMagick ; pkg set -A 0 anacron ; pkg set -A 0 choqok ; pkg set -A 0 chromium ; pkg set -A 0 clementine-player ; pkg set -A 0 epiphany ; pkg set -A 0 eom ; pkg set -A 0 filelight ; pkg set -A 0 filezilla ; pkg set -A 0 firefox ; pkg set -A 0 gedit ; pkg set -A 0 gimp ; pkg set -A 0 gnote ; pkg set -A 0 gwenview ; pkg set -A 0 hexchat ; pkg set -A 0 k3b ; pkg set -A 0 kate ; pkg set -A 0 konversation ; pkg set -A 0 life-preserver ; pkg set -A 0 lumina ; pkg set -A 0 mDNSResponder ; pkg set -A 0 nano ; pkg set -A 0 panicmail ; pkg set -A 0 pcbsd-meta-kde ; pkg set -A 0 pcbsd-meta-virtualbox ; pkg set -A 0 pcbsd-utils ; pkg set -A 0 pcbsd-utils-qt5 ; pkg set -A 0 py27-ranger ; pkg set -A 0 rsync ; pkg set -A 0 screenFetch ; pkg set -A 0 skype4 ; pkg set -A 0 smartmontools ; pkg set -A 0 sudo ; pkg set -A 0 thunderbird ; pkg set -A 0 virtualbox-ose ; pkg set -A 0 virtualbox-ose-kmod ; pkg set -A 0 vlc-qt4 ; pkg set -A 0 wine-devel ; pkg set -A 0 wine-gecko-devel ; pkg set -A 0 wine-mono-devel ; pkg set -A 0 xfburn
Mark ImageMagick-6.9.3.4,1 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark anacron-2.3_6 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark epiphany-3.16.3 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark eom-1.12.1 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark filelight-4.14.3 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark gedit-3.18.3 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark gnote-3.18.1 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark gwenview-4.14.3 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark kate-4.14.3 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark life-preserver-1456005125 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark mDNSResponder-576.30.4 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark virtualbox-ose-4.3.36 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark virtualbox-ose-kmod-4.3.36 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark vlc-qt4-2.2.1_7,4 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark wine-gecko-devel-2.44 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
Mark wine-mono-devel-4.5.6 as not automatically installed? [y/N]: y
[root@cces3-gjp4-pc-bsd-ergovista621] /usr/home/gjp4# exit
exit
[gjp4@cces3-gjp4-pc-bsd-ergovista621] ~% sudo pkg autoremove
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
Deinstallation has been requested for the following 338 packages:

Installed packages to be REMOVED:
        aisleriot-3.18.2
        gnome-games-3.18.0
        cinnamon-control-center-2.4.2_2
        gegl3-0.3.4
        gnome-photos-3.18.2
        gnome-utils-3.18.0,1
        thunar-archive-plugin-0.3.1_4
        squeeze-0.2.3_10
        xfce4-desktop-4.12.3
        Thunar-1.6.10_1
        foomatic-filters-4.0.17_5
        a2ps-4.13b_8
        accerciser-3.14.0_1
        gdm-3.16.4
        evince-3.18.2
        sushi-3.18.0
        gnome3-lite-3.18.0
        gnome-documents-3.18.2
        cinnamon-desktop-2.4.2_1
        nemo-2.4.5
        cinnamon-settings-daemon-2.4.3
        muffin-2.4.4
        cinnamon-screensaver-2.4.1
        gnome-font-viewer-3.16.2
        gnome-tetravex-3.18.0
        gnome-sudoku-3.18.2
        yelp-3.18.1
        gnome-contacts-3.18.0
        gnome-control-center-3.18.2
        gnome-shell-3.18.3
        gnome-terminal-3.18.1
        gnome-shell-extensions-3.18.3
        evolution-data-server-3.18.4
        gnome-todo-3.18.1
        cheese-3.18.1
        folks-0.11.1
        gnome-maps-3.18.2
        empathy-3.12.11
        gnome-calendar-3.18.2.1
        evolution-3.18.4
        libzapojit-0.0.3_1
        gfbgraph-0.2.3
        eog-plugins-3.16.3
        totem-3.18.1
        grilo-plugins-0.2.17
        brasero-3.12.1_1
        nautilus-3.18.5
        file-roller-3.16.4_1,1
        alacarte-3.11.91_2
        apg-2.3.0b_4
        gnome-settings-daemon-3.18.2
        colord-gtk-0.1.26
        gnome-color-manager-3.18.0
        orca-3.18.2
        py27-atspi-2.18.0
        caribou-0.4.19
        atomix-3.18.0
        vinagre-3.18.2
        avahi-gtk3-0.6.31_3
        avahi-header-0.6.31
        kdepim-4.14.3_3
        kopete-4.14.3_2
        kdenetwork-4.14.3
        baobab-3.18.1
        gcc-4.8.5_2
        lxterminal-0.2.0
        grub2-pcbsd-2.02q_8
        grub2-efi-2.02_15
        binutils-2.25.1,1
        bitstream-vera-1.10_7
        w3m-0.5.3_5
        tracker-1.6.1
        boehm-gc-threaded-7.4.2_4
        guile2-2.0.11_3
        boehm-gc-7.4.2_4
        bogofilter-1.2.4_5
        cabextract-1.6
        caja-extensions-1.12.0
        webkit-gtk3-2.4.9_1
        grilo-0.2.15
        gupnp-0.20.15
        opal-3.10.10_9
        ekiga-4.0.1_8
        cinnamon-menus-2.4.1
        cinnamon-session-2.4.3_1
        cinnamon-translations-2.4.2
        cjs-2.4.1
        clutter-gst-2.0.16
        mutter-3.18.2
        clutter-gtk3-1.6.6
        lightsoff-3.18.0
        libchamplain-0.12.12
        gnome-nibbles-3.18.2
        swell-foop-3.18.1
        quadrapassel-3.18.0
        gnome-2048-3.18.2
        clutter-gst3-3.0.14
        clutter-1.24.2
        cogl-1.22.0
        xfce4-wm-4.12.3
        coreutils-8.23
        libpwquality-1.2.4_1
        cracklib-2.9.6
        cups-pstoraster-8.15.4_8
        libmemcached-1.0.18_2
        dconf-editor-3.18.2
        mate-screensaver-1.12.0
        dmenu-4.6
        kaccessible-4.14.3
        kdeaccessibility-4.14.3
        jovie-4.14.3
        kdemultimedia-4.14.3
        dragon-player-4.14.3
        enca-1.18
        enscript-a4-1.6.6_1
        eog-3.18.1
        ptlib-2.10.11
        py27-papyon-0.5.4_1
        py27-telepathy-butterfly-0.5.15_2
        farsight2-0.0.31_3
        five-or-more-3.18.0
        py34-speech-dispatcher-0.8.3_1
        foomatic-db-hpijs-1.4
        foomatic-db-20150819
        four-in-a-row-3.18.2
        freedesktop-sound-theme-0.8
        krdc-4.14.3
        freerdp-1.2.0_5
        py27-pillow-2.9.0_1
        libass-0.13.1
        galculator-2.1.3
        xfce4-mixer-4.11.0_3
        xfce4-power-manager-1.5.2
        xfce4-battery-plugin-1.0.5_4
        xfce4-panel-4.12.0_1
        orage-4.12.1_1
        xfce4-settings-4.12.0_1
        xfce4-appfinder-4.12.0
        garcon-0.4.0_1
        gcc-ecj-4.5
        gconf-editor-3.0.1,1
        gedit-plugins-3.18.0
        libgweather-3.18.1
        gnome-clocks-3.18.0
        gnome-weather-3.18.1
        geocode-glib-3.18.1
        telepathy-logger-0.8.1
        gnome-characters-3.18.1
        totem-pl-parser-3.10.6
        gmime26-2.6.20
        gnome-backgrounds-3.18.0
        gnome-calculator-3.18.3
        gnome-chess-3.18.0
        gnome-session-3.18.1.2
        gnome-dictionary-3.18.1
        gnome-icon-theme-extras-3.12.0
        gnome-klotski-3.18.2
        gnome-mahjongg-3.18.0
        gnome-menus-3.13.3
        gnome-mines-3.18.2
        gnome-power-manager-3.18.0
        xfce4-terminal-0.6.3_2
        gnome-robots-3.18.1
        gnome-screenshot-3.18.0
        gnome-search-tool-3.6.0
        gnome-system-log-3.9.90
        gnome-system-monitor-3.16.0
        gnome-taquin-3.18.2
        gnome-themes-standard-3.18.0
        gnome-tweak-tool-3.18.1
        gnome-user-docs-3.18.1
        gnome-video-effects-0.4.1
        gnuchess-6.2.2
        seahorse-3.18.0
        libcryptui-3.12.2
        kget-4.14.3_1
        libkolab-0.5.3
        kdepim-runtime-4.14.3
        gpicview-0.2.4_1
        gsl-1.16_2
        gsound-1.0.2
        gssdp-0.14.13
        gstreamer1-plugins-vpx-1.6.3
        gstreamer1-plugins-v4l2-1.6.3
        gstreamer1-plugins-soup-1.6.3
        gstreamer1-plugins-jpeg-1.6.3
        gtk-vnc-0.5.4
        gtk-xfce-engine-3.2.0
        gucharmap-3.18.2
        highlight-3.28,2
        hitori-3.16.2
        i3lock-2.7
        i3status-2.10
        iagno-3.18.2
        zh-ibus-pinyin-1.5.0_1
        zh-ibus-chewing-1.4.14
        ibus-1.5.11
        xfce4-session-4.12.1_2
        libsocialweb-0.25.21_3
        juk-4.14.3
        kdemultimedia-ffmpegthumbs-4.14.3
        kdenetwork-filesharing-4.14.3
        kdenetwork-strigi-analyzers-4.14.3
        kmag-4.14.3
        kmix-4.14.3
        kmousetool-4.14.3
        kmouth-4.14.3
        krfb-4.14.3
        kscd-4.14.3
        leafpad-0.8.18.1_1
        xman-1.1.4
        libXprintUtil-1.0.1_3
        libbluray-0.7.0,1
        libbdplus-0.1.2
        libcanberra-gtk3-0.30_3
        libcheck-0.10.0
        libconfuse-2.7_1
        libcue-1.4.0_2
        libmusicbrainz3-3.0.3_4
        libdiscid-0.6.1
        libev-4.20,1
        pcmanfm-1.2.3
        libfm-1.2.3_3
        menu-cache-1.0.1
        lxpanel-0.6.2_1
        libfm-extra-1.2.3_3
        libgames-support-0.1
        lxsession-0.4.6.1_2
        libgee-0.18.0
        libgit2-glib-0.23.8
        libgit2-0.23.4
        libgnomekbd-3.6.0_1
        libkfbapi-1.0_3
        libkgapi-2.2.0
        libkolabxml-1.1.1
        libktorrent-1.3.1_7
        libmediaart-1.9.0
        libmicrohttpd-0.9.37_1
        libmms-0.6.4
        libmodplug-0.8.8.5_2
        libnfs-1.3.0_1
        libnice-gst010-0.1.13
        telepathy-gabble-0.18.3_2
        libquvi09-0.9.4_2
        libquvi-scripts09-0.9.20131130
        librtmp-2.4.20130923
        libssh2-1.6.0_1,2
        libsysinfo-0.0.2_1
        telepathy-mission-control-5.16.3_1
        libtelepathy-0.3.3_3
        libunistring-0.9.6
        libva-1.6.2
        libwraster-0.95.7_1
        libxdg-basedir-1.2.0_1
        py27-lxml-3.5.0
        linux-c6-devtools-6.7
        linux-c6-libgfortran-4.4.7_2
        lsof-4.90.b,8
        lua51-5.1.5_9
        lua52-lgi-0.9.0
        lxappearance-0.6.1
        lxde-common-0.5.5_5
        lxde-icon-theme-0.5.1
        lxinput-0.3.2_1
        lxmenu-data-0.1.4
        lxtask-0.1.4_2
        m4-1.4.17_1,1
        meanwhile-1.0.2_5
        mesa-demos-8.3.0
        mousepad-0.4.0_2
        mousetweaks-3.12.0
        mozo-1.12.0
        mpage-2.5.6
        mpc-1.0.3
        nanomsg-0.8.b
        nepomuk-widgets-4.14.3
        net-snmp-5.7.3_11
        o3read-0.0.4
        obkey-1.0
        obmenu-1.0_8
        xfce4-tumbler-0.1.31_2
        p5-AnyEvent-I3-0.16_1
        p5-AnyEvent-7.12,1
        p5-IPC-Run-0.94
        p5-IO-Tty-1.12_1
        p5-JSON-XS-3.01_2
        p5-Try-Tiny-0.24
        p5-Types-Serialiser-1.0_1
        p5-Unicode-Map8-0.13_1
        p5-Unicode-String-2.09_1
        p5-common-sense-3.73_1
        xarchiver-0.5.4_1
        pam_helper-1.0
        pl-libgadu-1.12.1,1
        polkit-gnome-0.105
        protobuf-c-1.2.1
        py27-cryptography-1.0.2_3
        py27-openssl-0.15.1
        py27-cffi-1.2.1
        py27-enum34-1.0.4
        py27-gstreamer-0.10.22_3
        py27-idna-2.0
        py27-ipaddress-1.0.14
        py27-libpeas-1.16.0
        py27-notify-0.1.1_11
        py27-pyasn1-0.1.9
        py27-pycparser-2.10
        py27-telepathy-python-0.15.19_1
        py27-tkinter-2.7.11_6
        zeitgeist-0.9.16
        py27-xdg-0.25
        py34-atspi-2.18.0
        py34-dbus-1.2.0_1
        py34-xdg-0.25_1
        py34-setuptools34-20.0
        qqwing-1.3.4_1
        raptor-1.4.21_5
        ristretto-0.8.0
        sdl_image-1.2.12_8
        spandsp-0.0.6
        tali-3.18.0
        telepathy-idle-0.2.0
        telepathy-salut-0.8.1_1
        thunar-vfs-1.2.0_11
        unoconv-0.6
        vino-3.18.1
        vte3-0.42.3
        wmicons-1.0_2
        wqy-fonts-20100803_5,1
        wv-1.2.9_3
        xcb-util-cursor-0.1.2
        xerces-c3-3.1.2
        xfce4-wm-themes-4.10.0_1
        xfontsel-1.0.5
        yelp-xsl-3.18.1
        zeroconf-ioslave-4.14.3
        zh-libchewing-0.4.0_1
        zh-pyzy-0.1.0_1

The operation will free 2 GiB.

Proceed with deinstalling packages? [y/N]: y
[1/338] Deinstalling gnome3-lite-3.18.0...
[2/338] Deinstalling gnome-utils-3.18.0,1...
[3/338] Deinstalling gdm-3.16.4...
==> You should manually remove the "gdm" user. 

To really remove the gdm port, please remove the following
directories manualy:

/var/cache/gdm /var/gdm /var/log/gdm and /var/run/gdm

[3/338] Deleting files for gdm-3.16.4: 100%

…

[20/338] Deinstalling brasero-3.12.1_1...
[20/338] Deleting files for brasero-3.12.1_1: 100%
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
[21/338] Deinstalling file-roller-3.16.4_1,1...
[21/338] Deleting files for file-roller-3.16.4_1,1: 100%

…

[28/338] Deinstalling nemo-2.4.5...
[28/338] Deleting files for nemo-2.4.5: 100%
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
[29/338] Deinstalling gnome-todo-3.18.1...
[29/338] Deleting files for gnome-todo-3.18.1: 100%

…

[45/338] Deinstalling aisleriot-3.18.2...
[45/338] Deleting files for aisleriot-3.18.2: 100%
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/usr/local/etc/gconf/schemas/aisleriot.schemas"
Failed to open `/usr/local/etc/gconf/schemas/aisleriot.schemas': 
[46/338] Deinstalling Thunar-1.6.10_1...
[46/338] Deleting files for Thunar-1.6.10_1: 100%

…

[69/338] Deinstalling kdepim-runtime-4.14.3...
[69/338] Deleting files for kdepim-runtime-4.14.3: 100%
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
[70/338] Deinstalling zh-ibus-pinyin-1.5.0_1...
[70/338] Deleting files for zh-ibus-pinyin-1.5.0_1: 100%
[71/338] Deinstalling zh-ibus-chewing-1.4.14...
[71/338] Deleting files for zh-ibus-chewing-1.4.14: 100%
[72/338] Deinstalling libfm-1.2.3_3...
[72/338] Deleting files for libfm-1.2.3_3: 100%
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
[73/338] Deinstalling lxpanel-0.6.2_1...
[73/338] Deleting files for lxpanel-0.6.2_1: 100%

…

[239/338] Deinstalling wqy-fonts-20100803_5,1...
/usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 21 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/100dpi: caching, new cache contents: 398 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/75dpi: caching, new cache contents: 398 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/Caladea: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/Carlito: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/Droid: caching, new cache contents: 23 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/GentiumBasic: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/Liberation: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/LinLibertineG: caching, new cache contents: 10 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/OTF: caching, new cache contents: 23 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/TTF: caching, new cache contents: 13 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/Type1: caching, new cache contents: 29 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/cantarell: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/cyrillic: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/dejavu: caching, new cache contents: 21 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/encodings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/encodings/large: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/gnu-unifont: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/misc: caching, new cache contents: 59 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/noto: caching, new cache contents: 158 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/util: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/webfonts: caching, new cache contents: 30 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/wqy: caching, new cache contents: 13 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/lib/X11/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/home/gjp4/.local/share/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/home/gjp4/.fonts: skipping, no such directory
Re-scanning /usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 21 dirs
Re-scanning /usr/local/share/fonts/encodings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/var/db/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/var/db/fontconfig: invalid cache file: 4682a3e4d52053cb6d3ed27f307ded4c-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: 5590eef8711d78f75a1d19f78ae9af8f-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: 00ed202266c19b8ebe5183686059cdcf-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: b9d2b94919fe346d8b04ef83de2b4cf0-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: 4c599c202bc5c08e2d34565a40eac3b2-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: d69df6005be9052cf14e7a84ff78d81b-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: 1fe06f2352c4cb897117a756a050a9d4-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: 6d95495df1dfa2220dadf839dce46f11-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: 4682a3e4d52053cb6d3ed27f307ded4c-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: 317e92aa1a4d3e601fb38e2d3c7b366a-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: ba1d92d9e40780c65c2952558e6fa6f5-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: b505adbf72d7253408dd67084a8aa967-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: 6e4e6e89d259e13805f6ecfb3b9855b6-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: d3b21a501470a17bfd0b9b6aedc735bd-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: 3a114eb8ff7128eaeed6b7525120b7d1-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded
[239/338] Deleting files for wqy-fonts-20100803_5,1: 100%
/usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 21 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/100dpi: caching, new cache contents: 398 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/75dpi: caching, new cache contents: 398 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/Caladea: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/Carlito: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/Droid: caching, new cache contents: 23 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/GentiumBasic: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/Liberation: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/LinLibertineG: caching, new cache contents: 10 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/OTF: caching, new cache contents: 23 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/TTF: caching, new cache contents: 13 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/Type1: caching, new cache contents: 29 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/cantarell: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/cyrillic: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/dejavu: caching, new cache contents: 21 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/encodings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/encodings/large: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/gnu-unifont: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/misc: caching, new cache contents: 59 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/noto: caching, new cache contents: 158 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/util: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/webfonts: caching, new cache contents: 30 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts/wqy: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/lib/X11/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/home/gjp4/.local/share/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/home/gjp4/.fonts: skipping, no such directory
Re-scanning /usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 21 dirs
Re-scanning /usr/local/share/fonts/encodings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/var/db/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/usr/home/gjp4/.cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: 17692e65f2842a3047704dc734d11f69-le64.cache-4
/usr/home/gjp4/.fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded
[240/338] Deinstalling wv-1.2.9_3...
[240/338] Deleting files for wv-1.2.9_3: 100%

…

[337/338] Deleting files for yelp-xsl-3.18.1: 100%
[338/338] Deinstalling zh-libchewing-0.4.0_1...
[338/338] Deleting files for zh-libchewing-0.4.0_1: 100%

…

[gjp4@cces3-gjp4-pc-bsd-ergovista621] ~% date ; uptime
Wed  2 Mar 2016 19:35:57 GMT
 7:35pm  up 1 hr, 3 users, load averages: 0.29, 0.44, 0.41
[gjp4@cces3-gjp4-pc-bsd-ergovista621] ~% freebsd-version
11.0-CURRENTNOV2015

…

[gjp4@cces3-gjp4-pc-bsd-ergovista621] ~% sudo pkg autoremove
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
Deinstallation has been requested for the following 41 packages:

Installed packages to be REMOVED:
        mate-polkit-1.12.0
        mate-base-1.12.0
        mate-applets-1.12.1_1
        accountsservice-0.6.40
        gnome-keyring-3.18.3
        mate-power-manager-1.12.1
        atril-1.12.2
        engrampa-1.12.0
        caja-1.12.3
        mate-terminal-1.12.1
        mate-media-1.12.1
        pinentry-gnome3-0.9.5_1
        vte-0.28.2_2
        gnome-pty-helper-0.40.2
        gtar-1.28_2
        mate-themes-1.12.2_1
        gtk-engines2-2.20.2_2
        gtk-murrine-engine-0.98.2_4
        pluma-1.12.1
        py27-gtksourceview-2.10.1_2
        gtksourceview2-2.10.5_4
        hal-info-20091130
        mate-utils-1.12.0
        marco-1.12.1
        mate-control-center-1.12.1
        mate-settings-daemon-1.12.1
        libmatekbd-1.12.1
        libmatemixer-1.12.1
        mate-panel-1.12.2
        libmateweather-1.12.1
        mate-system-monitor-1.12.1
        mate-notification-daemon-1.12.1
        libwnck-2.30.7_1
        libxklavier-5.3_1,1
        mate-backgrounds-1.12.0
        mate-icon-theme-faenza-1.12.0
        mate-menus-1.12.0
        mate-session-manager-1.12.1
        unique-1.1.6_6
        unzip-6.0_7
        zenity-3.18.0

The operation will free 342 MiB.

Proceed with deinstalling packages? [y/N]: y
[1/41] Deinstalling mate-base-1.12.0...
[2/41] Deinstalling mate-applets-1.12.1_1...
[2/41] Deleting files for mate-applets-1.12.1_1: 100%
[3/41] Deinstalling mate-control-center-1.12.1...
[3/41] Deleting files for mate-control-center-1.12.1: 100%
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
[4/41] Deinstalling mate-power-manager-1.12.1...
[4/41] Deleting files for mate-power-manager-1.12.1: 100%

…

[13/41] Deinstalling caja-1.12.3...
[13/41] Deleting files for caja-1.12.3: 100%
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
[14/41] Deinstalling mate-terminal-1.12.1...
[14/41] Deleting files for mate-terminal-1.12.1: 100%

…

[41/41] Deinstalling unzip-6.0_7...
[41/41] Deleting files for unzip-6.0_7: 100%
[gjp4@cces3-gjp4-pc-bsd-ergovista621] ~%
```

Answer (score 2):

With PC-BSD 11.0-CURRENTJUNE2016 I can reproduce the problem with fonts in KDE Plasma 4 (not in Lumina) by disabling anti-aliasing –

[image]

– or by disabling anti-aliasing then selecting system settings:

[image]

### Workaround

Enable anti-aliasing –

[image]

– after which, it's OK to re-select system settings:

[image]

---

I could not reproduce the problem that affected progress bars in Xfburn.